# ASP.Net Printer Friendly Page

Tags: asp.net, css, printing, asp.net-controls, print-css

Morning All,

I am trying to make a web page printer friendly.  I have managed to complete this for one of my pages perfectly fine by having another style sheet and the referencing this is my master page.

```
<link href="Styles/style2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="styles/style-print.css" media="print" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

The problem that i have is the main page i wish to have a printer friendly option hold is made up of ASP. Panel controls and these also have 1 or 2 subpanels. I used these panels to reduce clutter and scrolling.

If i add the relevant div tags to the main page i seem to only get the headers of these Panels and do not get the sub headings or and the content within these panels unless i collapse these panels before i click the printer friendly button.

This is not a task that i wish the user to complete also the printer friendly page looks horrible as i would like to remove the panel / boxes.   Is there a way for me to format this page so i dont get to see the panels but just the content when the users presses the pinter friendly button?

Regards
Betty.

Here is some sample code for my collopsible panels...

```
       <table>
            <tr>
                <td style="width:528px">
                    <h5>Topic</h5>
                </td>
                <td style="width:154px">
                    <h5>Presenter</h5>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <h5>Time</h5>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <!--   1.  HSE Issues (Main heading) -->
        <asp:Panel ID="pnlHeaderHSERegIssues" runat="server" CssClass="pnl" 
            Width="740px">
            <div style="float:left;">
                1. Safety, Health, Environmental &amp; Regulatory Issues
            </div>
            <div style="float:right;">
                <asp:Label ID="lblShowHideHSERegIssues" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </div>
            <div style="clear:both">
            </div>
        </asp:Panel>
        <!--   1.1  Safety Sub heading  -->
        <asp:Panel ID="pnlInfoHSERegIssues" runat="server" CssClass="pnlBody">
            <asp:Panel ID="pnlHeaderSafety" runat="server" CssClass="pnlBody2" Width="740px">
                <div style="float:left;">
                    1.1 - Safety Reviews
                </div>
                <div style="float:right;">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblShowHideSafety" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                </div>
                <div style="clear:both">
                </div>
            </asp:Panel>
            <asp:Panel ID="pnlInfoSafety" runat="server" CssClass="pnlBody">
                <table width="100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 510px">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtSafety" runat="server" Height="100px" 
                                style="font-family:Verdana" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="510px"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                        <td style="width: 140px" valign="top">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtSafetyPresenter" runat="server" Height="97px" 
                                style="font-family:Verdana" width="140px"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                        <td style="width: 57px" valign="top">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtSafetyTime" runat="server" style="font-family:Verdana" 
                                width="50px"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </asp:Panel>
          </asp:Panel>

        <!-- Collapse / un-collapse Panels (Main Heading) -->
        <asp:CollapsiblePanelExtender ID="CollapsiblePanelExtender" runat="server" 
            CollapseControlID="pnlHeaderHSERegIssues" Collapsed="true" 
            CollapsedText="Show Details" ExpandControlID="pnlHeaderHSERegIssues" 
            ExpandDirection="Vertical" ExpandedText="Hide Details" ScrollContents="false" 
            TargetControlID="pnlInfoHSERegIssues" TextLabelID="lblShowHideHSERegIssues">
        </asp:CollapsiblePanelExtender>
        <!-- Collapse / un-collapse Panels (sub Heading) -->
        <asp:CollapsiblePanelExtender ID="CollapsiblePanelExtender1" runat="server" 
            CollapseControlID="pnlHeaderSafety" Collapsed="true" CollapsedText="Show" 
            ExpandControlID="pnlHeaderSafety" ExpandDirection="Vertical" ExpandedText="Hide" 
            ScrollContents="false" TargetControlID="pnlInfoSafety" 
            TextLabelID="lblShowHideSafety">
       </asp:CollapsiblePanelExtender>
```

Comment: This seems as a solely css issue. Can you provide relevant parts of your code? Generated html + css. Not sure what does it have to do with Visual studio...Removing tags.

Comment: @walther.  I have edited the question to now include some code.